# Secure Module in Play Framework: Compilation error: Type Check already defined

Tags: playframework

I'm having an own security class, derived from the secure module of the play framework.
Unfortunately, i'm getting this error, while compiling the project:

Compilation error
The file {module:secure}/app/controllers/Check.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : The type Check is already defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this error when I removed this line from application.conf:

```
module.secure=${play.path}/modules/secure
```